# Emailing A Dynamically Created PDF Through PHP

Tags: php, email, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I've recently created an online template for creating job postings for our website. Everything is all done, it formats correctly in a browser, automatically posts to our website, bla bla bla.

The last piece I'm creating is to give the administrator a few options for distributing the posting to various places (via email) in a consistent, convenient way. I've created a PHP page that creates a PDF doc on the fly, using the TCPDF library. When loading pdf.php?id=X, the page displays a PDF with the content of job posting X. This means I'm never saving the PDF file to the server, just creating it on the fly each time it's called.

But I want to attach this PDF to an email, and send it to various colleges, and internal mailing lists, etc. If I attach the pdf.php?id=x to the email, it doesn't attach the PDF, it attaches what appears to be a blank file, with the above name.

Is it possible to attach this to the email without saving it to the server?

---

Below added based on JM4's response for further trouble shooting. I have put the PDF file creation into a function, and put it into an include file, just to keep things easier to manage.

```
// random hash necessary to send mixed content
$separator = md5(time());

$eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
$filename = "_Desiredfilename.pdf";

include_once('pdf.php');
// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$pdfdoc = job_posting_to_pdf($posting_id);
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

///////////HEADERS INFORMATION////////////
// main header (multipart mandatory) message
$headers  = "From: Sender_Name<valid_email@mydomain.com>".$eol;
//$headers .= "Bcc: email@domain.com".$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;

// message
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;

// attachment
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "--".$separator."--";

//Email message
if(mail('valid_email@mydomain.com', 'test job posting', 'message body goes here', $headers)) {
    echo 'mail sent';
} else {
    echo 'error in email';
}
```

Here is a stripped down version of pdf.php:

```
function job_posting_to_pdf($job_id) {
    require_once(ROOT . 'assets/libs/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
    require_once(ROOT . 'assets/libs/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); 

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('');
    $pdf->SetTitle('OPL Job Posting');
    $pdf->SetSubject('Job Posting');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

    // remove default header/footer
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    //set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(11, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, 11);

    //set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    //set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO); 

    //set some language-dependent strings
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l); 

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    $pdf->SetFont('times', 'I', 9);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $left_cell_width = 60;
    $row_height = 6;

    $pdf->Image(ROOT . 'assets/gfx/logos/OPL-Logo.jpg', 0, 5, null, 16, null, null, 'N', false, null,'R');
    $pdf->Ln('3');

    if(!$row['internal']) {
        $pdf->Cell(0,0,'This position will be posted internally and externally, concurrently.',0,2,'C');
    } else {
        $pdf->Cell(0,0,'Internal posting only.',0,2,'C');
    }

    //Remainder of actual PDF creation removed to keep things simple


    return $pdf->Output("", "S");
}
```

Comment: Show us the code (or preferably a very cut down skeleton). It sounds like the method you are using to turn the URL into a file attachment is wrong. Why are you so concerned about not writing a file even temporarily?

Comment: http://api.joomla.org/com-tecnick-tcpdf/TCPDF.html#methodOutput

I'm using the 'I' option for dest. I'm wondering if the S option is what I should be using.

Comment: did any of the answers here help you?

Comment: @Alex, no I've been off this project for several years now. I believe I just stored it to the temp folder and then attached it.

Comment: I've managed it myself in the meantime, thanks for the response though ;)

Comment: @Alex are any of the answers below correct? Can you add the correct solution so we can close this out?

Answer (score 6):

If I completely understand what you are asking this is quite simple. I am assuming you already have the PDF generated using something like fdpf or tcpdf. In that case - simply use the following code:

```
<?php
    // random hash necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());

    $eol = PHP_EOL;

    // attachment name
    $filename = "_Desiredfilename.pdf";

    // encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
    $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

    ///////////HEADERS INFORMATION////////////
    // main header (multipart mandatory) message
    $headers  = "From: Sender_Name<sender@domain.com>".$eol;
    $headers .= "Bcc: email@domain.com".$eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;

    // message
    $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;

    // attachment
    $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
    $headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
    $headers .= "--".$separator."--";


    //Email message
    mail($emailto, $emailsubject, $emailbody, $headers);

    ?>
```

Comment: You have the right idea. Everything here works, but when it gets to the line to actually send the email, it seems to hang indefinitely. No error, no nothing. Is there a limit to headers that can be passed in? This is a little over 810,000 chars (but it's just a one page PDF).

Comment: @Cory - My script works. if it is hanging, there is something wrong or different about your pdf script. I have used the above for 100 page pdfs without issue.

There is no limit to the number of headers than can be passed. Post your actual code in an edit so we can look.

Comment: Thanks JM4, I've added in the code in the original post.

Like I said, it will do everything but the actual mail() call. So I can output $headers via echo with no probs.

Comment: @Cory Dee - so you can confirm that the PDF is created however (running output, D or I)? What version of PHP are you running and what mail client in your php.ini settings?

Comment: Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.2.8. The mail settings in php.ini are set to the correct IP and port (I can send other emails). If I comment out the line with $headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol; it will send an email with a blank pdf attached. So mail is working.

Comment: Oh, and yes, it does generate a PDF file that can be loaded by a browser with no problems.

Comment: 800K is big in email terms. This sounds like a size limit problem. either sending or receiving.

Comment: @Talvi - 800k is the number of characters, not file size. Cory Dee - what happens when you change the last line in pdf.php to: return $pdf->Output("", "I");

Answer (score 1):

I just had to figure this out and my eyeballs were definitely sore by the end...

1) You need to install [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) to the php server.

2) Include the PHPmailer class in your TCPDF script, like so (your path may vary):

```
require_once('../PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php');
```

3) Now after your pdf code simply talk to PHPMailer like so:

```
$filename = "custompdf_$name_$time.pdf";

$pdf->Output($filename, 'F'); // save the pdf under filename

$mail = new PHPMailer(); $mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "mail.yourhost.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "user+yourhost.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "topsecret";        // SMTP account password

$mail->From = "noreply@yourhost.com";
$mail->FromName = "Stack Overflower";
$mail->AddAddress( $email, $name );  //  in this case the variable has been passed
$mail->AddCC( "person@somehost.net", "Johnny Person"); // in this case we just hard code it
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // use 2 for debugging the email send

$pdf_content = file_get_contents($filename);

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf_content, "custompdf_for_$name_$time.pdf", "base64", "application/pdf");  // note second item is name of emailed pdf
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Your pdf is here";
$mail->Body = "Dear $name,<br>
Here is your custom generated pdf generated at $t.<br><br>
Thank you";
if(!$mail->Send()) {
     echo "Sorry ... EMAIL FAILED"; 
     } else {  echo "Done. . .  Email sent to $email at $t."; }

unlink($filename); // this will delete the file off of server
```

Of course you have many options for the email sent, like not using html, or sending both html and text, adding many recipients and/or cc's, etc.

EDIT:  This does save the file temporarily on the server, but it cleans up after itself with the unlink command.

Comment: Your solution implies he needs to upload the PHP Mailer scripts to his directory which is not the case. Simple PHP Mail() commands will send email. You also do not need to save the PDF file as you implicate, it works just fine as $pdf->Output($filename, 'S');

Comment: Thanks- Actually, while mail works, phpmailer is way better, i.e. I needed the authenticated SMTP functions.  I suppose the 'S' option would keep the temp work in memory and not as an actual file on disk... if you can provide a working example...  I got a failed to open stream error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page which discusses advanced email in PHP.

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/advanced-email-php/5

They take an uploaded file and load the binary data into $data, but you can just start from there.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at sending it as an attachment via [PEAR Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/docs). It can accept an attachment as a string of data.

The RMail package also looks as if it will do the same via the stringAttachment class. You'll have to google for it, because I'm a new user and so I can post only one link at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree about using a mail library in place of building mime messages by hand with the default mail() function.  SwiftMailer is another good open source PHP mail library.  Here's the [sample code](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/dynamic-attachments) for using dynamic content as an attachment without having to save it to the file system first.

Answer (score 0):

Your headers seem to be a little out:

- `application/octet-stream` should become `application/octetstream`
- `Content-Disposition: attachment ..` should become `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"`

heres what the attachement headers should look like:

```
// attachment
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octetstream;".$eol; //Fixed
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$headers .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename(filename).'"'.$eol;
$headers .= 'Content-ID: <' . basename($filename) . '>' . $eol . $eol //EOL X2 Before
$headers .= $attachment;

//Run the above in a loop for multiple attachments, after add the final line
$headers .= '--' . $separator . '--' . $eol;
```

---

This was taken from one of my working applications, heres the loop if you wish to see it:

```
foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment) { 
     if (file_exists($attachment['file'])) {
        $handle = fopen($attachment['file'], 'r');
        $content = fread($handle, filesize($attachment['file']));

        fclose($handle); 

        $message .= '--' . $boundary . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Type: application/octetstream' . $this->newline;   
        $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($attachment['filename']) . '"' . $this->newline;
        $message .= 'Content-ID: <' . basename($attachment['filename']) . '>' . $this->newline . $this->newline;
        $message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    }
}
$message .= '--' . $boundary . '--' . $this->newline;
```

Comment: how would you do that if the pdf does not exist on the server but via url with tcpdf?